# How to convert the Core message to a JMS message?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I need to convert `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.message.impl.CoreMessage` to `javax.jms.Message`. How can i do this? Maybe there is a required util method somewhere in the code, or it needs to be done manually?

I want to intercept the following events:

- afterSend
- afterDeliver
- messageExpired

And then send the message to a direct endpoint Camel route which requires a `javax.jms.Message` instance.

Comment: `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.message.impl.CoreMessage`. I want to intercept message with `public void afterSend(ServerSession session, Transaction tx, Message message, boolean direct, boolean noAutoCreateQueue, RoutingStatus result) throws ActiveMQException`  method ActiveMQServerPlugin (receive `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.message.impl.CoreMessage`) and then send the message with Camel jms component (need `javax.jms.Message`)

Comment: That sounds like a real mess. What's the use-case for essentially injecting Camel into a core broker process?

Comment: For integration purpose need interceptor plugin, that can send intercepted messages to Camel route, direct endpoint

Comment: I want to intercept the next events: afterSend, afterDeliver, messageExpired, and then send message to direct endpoint Camel route. Non-exclusive divert doesn't` help in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to simply copy the message and route the copy to the address of your choice, e.g.:

```java
public class MyPlugin implements ActiveMQServerMessagePlugin {
   ActiveMQServer server;

   @Override
   public void registered(ActiveMQServer server) {
      this.server = server;
   }

   @Override
   public void afterSend(ServerSession session,
                         Transaction tx,
                         Message message,
                         boolean direct,
                         boolean noAutoCreateQueue,
                         RoutingStatus result) throws ActiveMQException {
      Message copy = message.copy();
      copy.setAddress("foo");
      try {
         server.getPostOffice().route(copy, false);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Then a Camel consumer can pick up the message and do whatever it needs to with it. This approach has a few advantages:

- It's *simple*. It would technically be possible to convert the `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.Message` instance into a `javax.jms.Message` instance, but it's not going to be straight-forward. `javax.jms.Message` is a JMS *client* class. It's not used on the server anywhere so there is no existing facility to do any kind of conversion to/from it.
- It's fast. If you use a `javax.jms.Message` you'd also have to use a JMS client to send it and that would mean creating and managing JMS resources like a `javax.jms.Connection` and a `javax.jms.Session`. This is not really something you want to be doing in a broker plugin as it will add a fair amount of latency. The method shown here uses the broker's own internal API to deal with the message. No client resources are necessary.
- It's asynchronous. By sending the message and letting Camel pick it up later you don't have to wait on Camel at all which reduces the latency added by the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

```
org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessage
```

This looks like the implementation of javax.jms.Message with an underlying org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ClientMessage which extends CoreMessage

Comment: Initially I have class `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.message.impl.CoreMessage`, couldn't find a way to convert to `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ClientMessage`